# Expresiones regulares PHP para contraseñas

Tags: php, regex

Estoy iniciando en PHP, humildemente solicito de su colaboración. Estoy tratando de realizar una expresión regular para que en PHP me acepte caracteres especiales tales como ($#!%&+-*,.) en el campo de "contrasena", actualmente lo tengo de la siguiente forma el cual solo me acepta números y letras.

`if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["usuario"]) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["contrasena"])) { ...`

He estado leyendo parte de la documentación pero no he logrado afinarlo, les agradezco mucho la ayuda que me puedan brindar. un saludo!

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Me parece que a tu POST contiene código no formateado, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: y que has intentado para agregar esos caracteres esepciales?

Comment: creo que con esto deberias bastar: `$pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&%*()\\-.+,/\"]'; ` y luego `if (preg_match('/^'.$pattern.'+$/', $_POST["usuario"]) && preg_match('/^'.$pattern.'+$/', $_POST["contrasena"])) {...` pruebalo y me avisas para agregarlo como respuesta

Comment: @ArcanisGK507, si con solo eso bastaba, me funciono perfectamente, pero me toco modificar solo un carácter de posición ```$pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&%*()\\-.+,\/"]';```. Te agradezco mucho tu ayuda.

Comment: dejame agregarlo como respuesta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algunos caracteres en regex necesitan utilizar el caracte de escape `/`, implementando tus caracteres quedaria asi:

```
$pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$&%*()\\-.+,\/"]';

if (preg_match('/^'.$pattern.'+$/', $_POST["usuario"]) && preg_match('/^'.$pattern.'+$/', $_POST["contrasena"])) {...
```

Resalto que la respuesta de [Arriel Costas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/553870/46896) tambien es funcional.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu colaboración, Arriel Costas Muchas gracias también por ayudar en este post.

Answer (score 0):

`$` en Regex indica "final", pero para que coincida con el carácter `$` propiamente dicho, usamos `\$`.

Así, para aceptar `$` y `-` se usaría `/^[A-Za-z0-9\$\-]$/` al ser `\` el carácter para "escapar" otros en una expresión. Con los otros caracteres es lo mismo: añadir \[caracter] entre los corchetes de la expresión.

P.D. Recomiendo utilizar https://regex101.com para comprobar las expresiones regulares, que además incluye una explicación de cada parte de esta y una referencia rápida.

Comment: te faltaron los otros caracteres que pidio: $#!%&+-*,.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 sí, pero como indico en la respuesta, los demás se hacen todos de la misma manera

Comment: y cual es esa misma manera? como sabes que no copio y pego el codigo de su proyecto sin saber que hace el regex por que fue otro el que lo hizo... o si alguien viene buscando tu respuestas y no sabe nada de regex ... recuerda que respondes a la comunidad no solo al OP.

Comment: entre mejor sea tu respuesta y mas completa este mejor sera recivida por la comunidad.

Comment: tambien te invito a que participes de los chat si llegas a tener dudas: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132548/php-en-espanol y https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol